# xhr [Chrome] to send Form data working on Linux (Debian) but not Windows (10)

Tags: google-chrome, angular, xmlhttprequest

In my Angular 2 application (but I guess it's not related to Angular but the browser instead, since I'm using xhr directly), I am sending form data (a file + an object stringified).

The issue is that on Chrome on **Linux (Debian)** it just **works** whereas still on **Chrome** but running on **Windows (10)** it doesn't.

**Code:**

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let form = new FormData();

form.append('file', file, file.name); // the file is loaded correctly
form.append('payload', JSON.stringify(data)); // data is just a JSON object

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
     if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
         // we arrive here both on Debian and Windows 10
     }
} 
xhr.upload.onerror = function() { .... } // no error

xhr.open('POST', 'http://<my_url>', true);
xhr.send(form);
```

Looking @ **DevTools -> Network -> http://my_url**, the request payload is the same: (this is from Debian)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVBFM8mVbOsD54jDd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="my file.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

------WebKitFormBoundaryVBFM8mVbOsD54jDd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="payload"

{"property1": "x", "property2": "y"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryVBFM8mVbOsD54jDd--
```

The only difference I see is that the **Content-type** of the file (in **payload**) on Windows is **application/octet-stream** (which as far as I see could be the cause as it's considered a "generic" file, **not a text file of type .csv**)

**Any clue why is this happening? Anything wrong with my code?** (which seems to be working **only** on Linux, no matter which browser on Windows or Os X)

Comment: Define "not working." If the code is sending a request then I'd say it's working. Now, if the server is behaving differently based on the `Content-Type`, that's another issue.

Comment: It might be this line:

if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
         // we arrive here both on Debian and Windows 10
     }

Could you try?:

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(xhr.response);                        
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

Comment: @Dan, yes I mean that by "not working" (basically the question is why Chrome is sending a different content type? / Bhetzie yes I'll try (by this week)

Comment: @Dan since you may be right (but can't now until don't solve the other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934531/how-to-use-xhr-overridemimetype-in-chrome-ie-edge). You can answer tothe question with that and if I solve the other doubt (see link) I'll accept that too.
@ Bhetzie DONE = status 4. so what does it change? :)