# how to use xhr.overrideMimeType in Chrome / IE Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue with sending a file (part of a request in form data format).

The issue seems coming from the fact that **only** in **Chrome** for **Linux** the file (which is CVS file, with .csv extension and basically just text) is sent with mimetype  (Content-type in request body) **Content-Type: application/octet-stream**

So, I am trying to **override** the mimetype to match the same sent by **Chrome** on **Linux** which is **text/csv**.

However the mimetype is apparently **not** overriden and still send as **octet-stream**.

My code:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
let form = new FormData();

form.append('file', file, file.name); // the file is loaded correctly
form.append('payload', JSON.stringify(data)); // data is just a JSON object

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
     if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
         // we arrive here both on Debian and Windows 10
     }
} 
xhr.upload.onerror = function() { .... } // no error

xhr.open('POST', 'http://<my_url>', true);

console.log(file.type);
xhr.overrideMimeType("text/csv");

xhr.send(form);
```

A couple of notes:

- console.log(file.type) actually **prints** "text-csv" but only in **Chrome for Linux (Debian specifically)**. in the other cases (any other browser or platform) **nothing** is printed
- given the previous point, it seems clear to me for some reason any other browser / platform **can't recognize the file type**, so the file is sent as **octet-stream** (general binary file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`xhr.overrideMimeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/overrideMimeType) changes the MIME-type of the *response*, not the request.

I you want to change the MIME-type of the file, just create a new [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) with an explicit file type:

```js
var blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'text/csv'});
form.append('file', blob, file.name);
```

The above changes the MIME-type of the file in the uploaded form to "text/csv", as desired.

PS. If you literally want to change the MIME-type of the *whole* request (instead of just the file), use `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'custom MIME type here');`. (This only makes sense if you are sending a non-standard or custom data in the `xhr.send` method).

Comment: thanks Rob. so basically, I take the "file" variable (which is a blob), I use it to create a new blob with a different type?

Comment: never mind, it worked!
but can you clarify why one should actually use overrideMimeType?

Comment: @dragonmnl E.g. `xhr.responseXML` is only set if the response is a XML document. If you are expecting a XML response, but the server does not correctly set the MIME-type of the response, then you can override the MIME-type to make sure that the browser attempts to parse the response as XML, using `xhr.overrideMimeType('application/xml')`